# Passing objects into yield statement in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a script that makes various read requests from a database (I have many methods similar to the `read()` method). I'd like to avoid repeating the code for creating and closing the cursor. So I am using a context manager and generator hand-in-hand. (In the below code, `db_connection` is a mysql connector object.)

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

class DatabaseReader():
  def __init__(self, db_connection):
    self.db_connection = db_connection
    self.num = num

  @contextmanager
  def connect(self):
    cursor = self.db_connection.cursor(buffered=True)
    try:
      yield
    finally:
      cursor.close()

  def read(self):
    with self.connect():
      cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM table;")
```

However, calling the 'read' method gives me an `AttributeError` as `cursor` is not defined. How can I "pass" the cursor object to the yield statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your custom implementation you need to "yield" a `cursor` object which will be bound  in the `as` clause of the `with` statement:

3 fixes required in your code:

- passing `num` to be assigned to `self.num = num`
- yielding `cursor`
- adding `as` keyword to `with` statement

---

```
from contextlib import contextmanager


class DatabaseReader():

    def __init__(self, db_connection, num):
        self.db_connection = db_connection
        self.num = num

    @contextmanager
    def connect(self):
        cursor = self.db_connection.cursor(buffered=True)
        try:
            yield cursor
        finally:
            cursor.close()

    def read(self):
        with self.connect() as cur:
            cur.execute("SELECT * FROM table;")
```

Comment: Thanks, I think there's a typo in the second last line (`cur` should be `cursor`). I'll suggest an edit immediately after adding this comment.

Comment: @wwl, one advice: be careful using asterisk `*` in sql query could be "stunning" )) (if you have a big table)

Comment: Thanks. I actually am not using SELECT * FROM table, I merely used it as dummy code for the purpose of asking this question

Comment: i guess he wants try :  cursor = self.db_connection.cursor(buffered=True) cursor. close, return cursor. no need to yield one value.